# Is there a way to figure out if 2 (or more) address is belong to same HD Wallet account or not?

Tags: wallets, addresses, hd-wallets

I'm a new to Wallet concept, I know that a HD Wallet structure is created from a `root seed` as Mnemonic Code, from that HD Wallet help to generate child keys as the meaning of multiple difference Ethereum Address.

So, is there a way that we can follow to figure out or verify if 2 address is belong to a HD Wallet (or the `root seed`) or not?

Many thanks for all contributing,

Comment: So there used to be some privacy vulns with certain implementations of HD wallets (read here: https://bitcoinmagazine.com/articles/deterministic-wallets-advantages-flaw-1385450276/) but I dont think its the case anymore as most, especially in Ethereum, have eliminated the weird "master pub key" situation